# Dibujar polyline en mapa datos de un json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Amigos tengo un problema los pongo en contexto, tengo un json con todas las coordenadas de las localidades (upz) de la ciudad de Bogotá, ese json me muestra la siguiente información.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero dibujar esas coordenadas en mi mapa con folium y tengo el siguiente código:

```
# import folium library
import folium

# create a map object
mapObj = folium.Map(location=[24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000],
                    zoom_start=5)

# create a polyline with the coordinates
# df_loc["geometry"]["coordinates"]
folium.PolyLine(df_loc["geometry"], color="red", weight=2).add_to(mapObj)
# folium.PolyLine([(19.0821978, 72.7411), (28.6471948, 76.9531796), (24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000)], color="red", weight=2).add_to(mapObj)
```

pero me esta generando un error que no logro entender
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en el mundo espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano les agradezco, muchas gracias.

Comment: El error te dice que hay un string y al tratar de hacer la conversión a `float` obviamente falla. Lo que puedes hacer es verificar los datos para saber donde está ese string y ver que operación de limpieza o pre-procesamiento debes de hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código que pones muestra como es la estructura del parámetro `folium.PolyLine([(19.0821978, 72.7411), (28.6471948, 76.9531796), (24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000)], color="red", weight=2)`, el cual he confirmado primero en un script personal que tenía.

Nótese que la forma correcta es: `[(19.0821978, 72.7411), (28.6471948, 76.9531796), (24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000)]`

Lo que estás tratando de pasarle es en cambio una serie de pandas con elementos:
`{type: 'Point',coordinates:[lat,long]}`

Debes mapear cada elemento de la serie para obtener cada `[lat,long]` en una lista de tuplas.

Agrego [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054208/13636459) similar en inglés que confirma.

También la [documentación oficial: PolyLine](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine)

> class folium.vector_layers.PolyLine(locations, popup=None, tooltip=None, **kwargs)

> Parameters
> locations **(list of points (latitude, longitude))** – Latitude and Longitude of line (Northing, Easting)